# Fractional derivatives in different coordinates

Tags: derivatives, coordinate-systems, partial-fractions

I wonder how fractional derivatives are defined in cylindrical coordinate?
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How do you define your fractional derivative

Comment: $F(\partial^{\alpha}_x f(x)) = -|k|^{\alpha} f(k)$
 this is the difinition in fourier space @GuyFsone